# No Python Folder in " Documents "?

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to learn python from a video. The first step is to install and to go to Documents/Python where he has a bunch of files. I do not however have that folder. Cant find it on google so far either. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

https://youtu.be/myFD0np9eys?t=219  <-- Video

Comment: Hi Daryll, some users have downvoted your question due to the fact that it is a little bit vague. For further reference, please see this article on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it seems vague, but when you dont know whats going on, you cant be more detailed. I watched the video, he installed the program, then went to a folder that he did not explain was there. He said.. install python.. check it works in command prompt, then went right into telling me to cd documents / cd python. I know its easy to see when you know what python is and how it works, but as someone that has never used it, this is not obvious. But thank you SO much for the help, i would have been lost without it. :) Yes im a dumb n00b.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that folder because that's a folder he created to put all of his python programs (that he has already made) into. Please watch further into the video and/or watch the video more closely. He is simply showing you how to navigate your computer using the Command Prompt by using the `cd` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please remember though that im completely new. His steps of explanation were to install python, check to see if it works, then to go to that folder, Im sure to someone that knows python its a obvious answer, but to me i thought it was supposed to be there as part  of the installation and i had done something wrong. I did watch a bit further and it seemed that he moved on and i was missing something important. Yes im a green n00b, so thank you VERY much for your help. Was so confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the video, he changes the current working directory using `cd`. In his case, all of the python files that show up are the ones he has personally created in his Documents folder. You simply just have to navigate to wherever you save the python files you want to run. For example, if you have a folder on your desktop called "PythonProjects" and within that folder you have a python script titled "foo.py," you would type in the command prompt / terminal:

```
cd Desktop/PythonProjects
```

Then to run the file:

```
python foo.py
```

Comment: Thank you so much. To me it seemed as if those were installed, as well as the folder, when he installed python and were part of the installation. I watched a bit further, but he seemed from my perspective to move on to creation, so i stopped because i was lost. Thank you so much for your explanation, i know to many i look really stupid or like i didnt put in the effort, but it was from a place of total ignorance. I know that can be hard to grasp when you know abut a topic how someone can be so green to it. Thank you for being nice and helping me.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In the video he has put all of his python programs and modules in a folder called Documents , hence he is getting the list of files , not necessary that you would have those files in the first place as he has downloaded a lot of packages , you might have a default location which is generally.
C:\Users\username\Appdata\Local\programs\python\python38-32
And not one more thing the python38-32 in the location i specifeid is my python version (python 3.8) if urs is python 3.7 you may want to enter python37-32 instead . Hope this answer helps you .

Comment: Thank you so much and thank you for not making me feel stupid. When you are 100% new to a thing, stuff like this can be confusing. I had no idea they were modules, i thought it was supposed to be there as part of the installation and i did something wrong. Thank you so much again, stay safe out there.

Comment: Welcome Daryll Gomas , and yes these stuff might be confusing in the starting but as you learn more and deep all this stuff will seem very simple . All the best for learning ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try searching for cmd commands to search for the folder, plus there's not really any reason to open the Python folder as you can save all your work in a new folder in the desktop if you make one

Comment: Yup, makes sense now. Was just confusing when you know 0 about coding/python. He didnt explain in the video that he made that folder and the things in it were what he put there, so i thought i messed up the install or installed the wrong version of python. I can see how it looks stupid or lazy from the outside, but i spent like 20 minutes trying to figure it out. Thanks man, your input is valued.